# Toggle view of list elements on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, touch

I'm trying to deal with some sort of toggle view effect on a HTML unordered list.
What I'm trying to do is switch `DIV` views inside a `LI`, using jquery (not jquery mobile), when I touch it on a touch screen device and restore view when tapping somewhere else outside the current `LI`.

this is a HTML example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item1">
     <div class="div1">Info</div>
     <div class="div2" style="display:none;">Tools</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item2">
     <div class="div1">Info</div>
     <div class="div2" style="display:none;">Tools</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item3">
     <div class="div1">Info</div>
     <div class="div2" style="display:none;">Tools</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So basically if I tap on "item2", "div1" should hide and "div2" should be visible, inside "div2" are some buttons that you can interact with. But then, when I touch outside "item2", "div1" should be visible again and "div2" should hide.
I tried using `nouseenter` and  `mouseleave` with jquery, but it causes a mess when you try to scroll or tap the other `LI` elements in the same list, also tried using `toggle`, but so far no luck. Now I can't find a simple but effective way to achieve what I want, hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is a working example that doesn't work properly on touch devices http://jsfiddle.net/T5HMt/44/

Comment: What functionality you want for the case when user clicks item2 (on this event div2 of item2 will be visible and div1 will hide) and then again user clicks on item2.

Comment: Well, nothing happens if you click on div2, since the idea is to have some buttons inside div2 that will not interact with the current list

Comment: great. One more question/understanding in regards to your requirement. If user clicks on item1 then on item2 and then on item3, then div2 of all these li will be visible, and then if user taps somewhere else on the screen then you want all div2 to hide and all div1 to show. Am I correct pertaining to your requirement?

Comment: Based on my understanding, I have posted the solution in answer section. please take a look at the code and fiddle provided. Let me know if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like I found a way to solve my own problem with a solution very similar to the one provided by Tushar Raj. Instead of displaying the hidden div on mouse over I did it on a click event and then hide it on mouse leave.
The thing is that `mousenter` triggers two things at the same time on touchscreens, the first thing is a 'mouseenter' event and then a 'touchstart' event, so if you have links inside the div that is being displayed on the mouseenter event, they will also be 'clicked'.

```
$(document).on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).find('.main').hide();
            $(this).find('.second').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function (event) {
            $(this).find('.main').show();
            $(this).find('.second').hide();
        }
    },'.search');
```

And a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/T5HMt/58/) it works as expected on touch screens

Thanks to everyone for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want corresponding div2 to show and to hide div1 when li is tapped (example- On tap event on "item2", "div1" of "item2" should hide and "div2" of "item2" should be visible). And you want to show "div1"and hide "div2" only when user taps somewhere outside the li (outside any LI mentioned in your question).

Please check this code if it helps you.

```
$(".item1, .item2, .item3").click(function(){
      $(this).children(".div2").css("display", "block");
      $(this).children(".div1").css("display", "none"); 
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).parents().is('.item1') && !$(target).parents().is('.item2') && !$(target).parents().is('.item3')) {
         $(".div2").css("display", "none");
          $(".div1").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Working fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/5jpyzkmt/

In the fiddle I have given border to LI just to illustrate it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, It works well but something I didn't mention is that each 'li' is created programmatically, also, I would like to hide the opened 'li' when I click another 'li' within the same list. I updated my answer with a working example to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try **hover** . It should work for **touch devices** too .

```
 $('.item1,.item2,.item3').on('hover',function(){
       $(this).find('.div1').hide();
       $(this).find('.div2').show();
  },function(){
       $(this).find('.div1').show();
       $(this).find('.div2').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you can't use 'hover' with 'on' event, instead you have to use mouseenter, mouseleave methods. I tried your solution already and it doesn't work well on touch devices, it seems like a good solution but I think the best approach would be using 'click' events or something similar.